# Entity Framework Core filter related entities and get top 2 for each group

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.0.1 and I have the following models

```
public class Article
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public int Approved { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArticleDate { get; set; }

    // ... some other fields

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleCategoryRelation> ArticleCategoryRelations { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //... soem other fields
    [ForeignKey("ArticleCategoryParent")]
    public int? ArticleCategoryParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ArticleCategory ArticleCategoryParent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleCategoryRelation> ArticleCategoryRelations { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleCategoryRelation
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ArticleCategoryId { get; set; }
    public ArticleCategory ArticleCategory {get; set;}
}
```

Every article belongs to one or more categories. Categories might have parent category.

I want to get from database last two articles (where Approved = 1) with related category details, for each category that belongs to a parent category which id is given as input.

I have tried but with no success. I can't filter results of an `.Include()` entity. Is it possible... or I don't know how to do it?

All my data are accessed through entity framework with `appContext` (the context used to get entities from database). Can I achieve what I want through entity framework core (lambda expression is preferred over Linq if possible), or should I use ADO.NET library (which I know how to execute custom queries).

P.S. I want to get data only to show in the view... no edit is needed.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to include here at all, as far as I can tell. Whenever you use data from a nav property, EF will go get the data from that table, as best it can filter it.

```
var CategoriesUnderParent = AppContext.ArticleCategories
.Where(c => c.ArticleCategoryParent == {parent});

foreach(var category in CategoriesUnderParent)
{
    var ArticlesAllowed = category.ArticleCategoryRelations
         .Where(acr => acr.Article.Approved == 1).Select(a => a.Article);

    var ArticlesPicked = ArticlesAllowed
         .OrderByDescending(ar => ar.ArticleDate)
         .Take(2);
   // Do something with your data
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SomeGuy, with some modification of your code I managed to solve my problem. I have combined the two statements inside the loop because I don't think that might be any difference.

Comment: Is there any way not to loop to get the results?

Comment: @Endri There is no difference between using two statements and combining into one, so you're fine there. You could do this without a loop via selectmany, but I would opt against it because it makes the code less clear.

Comment: In this case I don't have performance issues. I want to know if SelectMany performs better than looping each element?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would imagine selectmany performs better than foreach provided you're filtering against an indexed field (in datastructure that support them, such as entity framework's IQueryables), and very slightly worse otherwise.